# How to optimize query with two inner join

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

Using this query to get the products with words that fulfill all three required word terms (lenovo, laptop, computer):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.price FROM
(SELECT p.id AS productid, name, price 
FROM products p JOIN productwords pw ON p.id = pw.productid 
JOIN words w ON pw.wordid = w.id WHERE word.term = 'lenovo') t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT p.id AS productid, name, price
FROM products p JOIN productwords pw ON p.id = pw.productid 
JOIN words w ON pw.wordid = w.id WHERE word.term = 'laptop') t2
INNER JOIN
(SELECT p.id AS productid, name, price
FROM products p JOIN productwords pw ON p.id = pw.productid 
JOIN words w ON pw.wordid = w.id WHERE word.term = 'computer') t3
ON
t1.productid = t2.productid
AND
t1.productid = t3.productid
ORDER BY t1.name
```

As far as I can see, the query considers the whole words table for each term (the tables have indexes. Database is MySql).

Can the query be rewritten in a better way, so it will become faster? (the tables contain millions of rows)

For example with subsets, so the 'laptop' search only considers the rows matching 'lenovo' - and the 'computer' search only considers the rows matching first 'lenovo' and then 'laptop'.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT p.id AS productid, name, price 
FROM products p
JOIN productwords pw ON p.id = pw.productid 
JOIN words w ON pw.wordid = w.id
WHERE word.term in ('lenovo','computer','laptop')
GROUP BY p.id , name, price 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT word.term) = 3
```

That is if I understood the question, it looks like product -> words is 1:n relation , and if no column from the `word` table is selected, that should work perfectly.

Comment: Nice one. Performance went from 0,027 seconds to 0,015 seconds for query that matches 30 products. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) @Louisa

Comment: Do you have a trick here too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518561/getting-the-number-of-matches-for-various-word-combinations

Answer (score 0):

This might be a quicker way of doing it:

`SELECT p.id, name, price
FROM products p
where 
EXISTS (select null 
    from productwords pw1 
    JOIN words w1 ON pw1.wordid = w1.id
    where w1.term = 'lenovo'
          and p.id = pw1.productid )
and EXISTS (select null 
    productwords pw2 
    JOIN words w2 ON pw2.wordid = w2.id
    where w2.term = 'laptop'
          and and p.id = pw2.productid )
and EXISTS (select null 
    productwords pw3 ON p.id = pw3.productid 
    JOIN words w3 
    where w3.term = 'computer'
          and p.id = pw3.productid )

ORDER BY name;`

Comment: It will probably be the same